# script to set sublist filed value to null

Tags: netsuite

With in return authorization how can we default the value of item rate  value to null to avoid  over refunding? Somehow below doesn't work.What's the issue?

```
function rate_clientPageInit() 
    {
    if (!nlapiGetRecordId())
    for (var i = 1; i <= nlapiGetLineItemCount("item"); i++) 
    {
    nlapiSetLineItemValue("item", "discountrate", i, null);
    }
    }
```

Comment: did you try to log what does `nlapiGetLineItemCount("item")` returns & Whether it entering in to the loop or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using nlapiSelectLineItem, nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue and nlapiCommitLineItem instead of nlapiSetLineItemValue